# has_many relationship on same model, multiple field names

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations, mongoid

I have a model `Company` which has the fields:

```
  field :label,              type: String
  field :logo_url,           type: String
  field :status,             type: String
  belongs_to :company_lists, :class_name => 'Models::Persistence::CompanyList'
```

and `CompanyList`

```
  field :label,            type: String
  field :status,           type: String
  has_and_belongs_to_many :companies, inverse_of: nil
```

I have `Curriculum` model, where there could be 2 types of company lists say `hiring_company_list`, `sponsoring_company_list`.

How should the `Curriculum` model have the same `has_many` on `CompanyList` but with different names so that each list ID could be different (not alias). Also the `Curriculum` should have only one type of each company list.

Comment: If the relationships between these models vary, that's an indication you need to redesign it. Perhaps `CompanyList` and `CurriculumList` could be of type `List` (inherit from it) and in each of these models you define the unique relationship.

Comment: Ok. Is there a way for me to use the `has_many` on the same model but have different field names?

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: I want to use the `has_many company_list` in my `curriculum` but I want to have 2 such associations, but with a  different name as they are different fields. How can I do that?

Comment: I see there's a new answer. I'm trying to get you to describe to us what you mean by "different name" and "different fields." It would help to have an example of the `Curriculum` model laid out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you want on `Curriculum` have two `has_many` that point to the `Company` model through different names right?, Well why not just use a `has_many through` association?

```
class CurriculumCompanyList < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :curriculum
end

class Curriculum < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :curriculum_company_lists
  #here could be has_many as well if you point directly to companies instead of companylist
  has_one :hiring_company_list, through: :curriculum_company_lists
  has_one :sponsoring_company_list, through: :business_line_subscriptions
end

class CompanyList < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :curriculum_company_lists
  has_many :curriculums, through: :curriculum_company_lists
end
```

This way you can easily access the different types of company lists from Curriculum:

```
curriculum = Curriculum.create
curriculum.sponsoring_company_list
curriculum.hiring_company_list
```

Comment: YES! THIS IS WHAT I WAANNNNTTTT.

Comment: Ha sorry http://giphy.com/gifs/betawards-bet-awards-2014-l46CcM0NK1ucuLkjK